# mvc3 embed a partial view within another

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a partial view which consists of a div with a benner that I change once a week.
This banner is embedded within 10 pages that have the same layout.

Give a page like Index.cshtml or AboutUs.cshtml, both being partial views and having the laypout _Layout.cshtml my question is:

Can I inser code in Index.cshtml or AboutUs.cshtml that renders Banner.cshtml?

something like:

inside Index.cshtml or AboutUs.cshtml  I have @Html.Renderbanner("banner.cshtml");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Banner"); }
```

In your shared view folder, add your partial view and call it _Banner.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could always:

```
@Html.Partial("Banner")
```

from any view or partial view. This will render the `Banner.cshtml` partial at the place where you called this helper.

Answer (score 1):

Use @Html.RenderPartial("YourViewName");

Answer (score 0):

First, just to clarify: Are Index and AboutUs really partial views in your scenario? That may 
change my advice, but normally I see three options:

1. **Razor Helper**, create Banner.cshtml in App_Code with the following code:

   ```
   @helper Show(){
       <img src="mybanner.png"/>
   }
   ```

   Then call in Index.cshtml:

   ```
   @Banner.Show()
   ```
2. **Html Helper Extension**, a bit overkill here probably (see tutorial on web)
3. **Partial View**: Create "_MyBanner.cshtml" and use the following in Index.cshtml:

   ```
   @Html.Partial("_MyBanner");
   ```

(Number 3 is the one that might be tricky if Index and AboutUs are also partial views, but 1 the one I would choose.)

*Note: There is a difference between Html.Partial and Html.RenderPartial. The latter writes directly to the output stream and will require you to call it in parentheses. In MVC AFAIK it is best practice to use Html.Partial.*

Answer (score 0):

You can create a RenderSection in layout.cshtml

```
 @if (IsSectionDefined("Sidebar"))
    { 
        <div id="page">
            <!-- end #content -->
            <div id="content">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar">
                @RenderSection("Sidebar", required: false)
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end #page -->
        <!-- end #sidebar -->

    }
    else
    {
        <div id="page">
            <!-- end #content -->
            <div id="content2">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end #page -->
        <!-- end #sidebar -->

    }
```

if you need see the secction in about.cshtml

use

```
@section Sidebar{
    @Html.Partial("_yourbanner")
}
```

if you dont need the banner do not include it